# Declaring vector variable in the Verilog not starting with the MSB(e.g,. reg var[0][20])

Tags: verilog

I am familiar to the syntax described in [here](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00057.htm)

> net_type [msb:lsb] list_of_net_identifiers;
>
> reg [msb:lsb] list_of_register_identifiers;

For example, to declare the 32bits memory address, I could use the syntax like

```
reg [31:0] address;
```

Also to declare the memory comprised of the 16 elements which consist of 32 bits each,

```
reg [31:0] mem [15:0];
```

However, I could frequently face the syntax like below to declare multidimensional arrays.

```
reg [31:0] mem [0:15]
```

I've googled it and found one related article in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715423/declaring-variable-in-verilog-with-indexing-that-doesnt-start-at-zero).
It seems that whether the larger number comes first or not, the first number before the colon (:) is the MSB and the LSB follows. It seems like the difference comes from the preference of coding.

However, I think mixing [31:0] and [0:15] style is little bit count-intuitive and confusing even though it depends on the preference. I could see a lot of mixing especially in the declaration of multi-dimensional arrays. Why is it allowed to be used? Is there any advantage that I couldn't notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Verilog, the numeric index ordering of a memory is only a matter of preference except when loading the memory from a text file. The first line in the file represents the *left* index, and like most other languages, starts at 0, so [0:15] is the more common way to declare a memory range. Otherwise there is no advantage one way or the other in how you declare a memory range since you canny only reference one memory element at a time.

The same can be said about a vector if you never plan to access individual bits of the vector. But once you do, how you address each bit becomes *significant* in position of an integral value.

In SystemVerilog, the ordering of both the vector width and memory dimensions becomes significant because you can stream memories as a whole and well as selects parts just like you do a vector.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. I've tried to figure out how the declaration affects the endianness of number stored in the memory by using code in [here](https://pastebin.com/hphP2Sgz). To make sure that I understand correctly, the [0:7] or [7:0] declaration doesn't affect the way that synthesized gate store the number in BIG endian or LITTLE endian, but it only determines how to access each bytes with indices ([0:7]=> accessed like BIG_ENDIAN, [7:0]=> accessed like LITTLE_ENDIAN). Is it correct?

Comment: Correct -------